# How to make coins fly toward coin meter like Temple Run unity

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, unity-game-engine, meter

Can anyone help me to fly coins toward the coins meter.

I have try this code.

```
 public GameObject meter;

 void Update () {

     transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, meter.transform.position, 1.5f * Time.deltaTime);

 }
```

But it's not working for me. Maybe because the CoinsMeter is UiImage with text in my case. So please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dummy gameobject behind your coin meter and set your coins' Target position to that dummy gameobject position.

**Edit**:

Since your camera position might change, the above one doesn't work in such cases.
Do like,

```
Vector3 target = uiObject.transform.position + offset;
Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(target);
```

Now, worldPoint is your new target position.

Comment: Thats what i was trying to explain with a little bit more details. This should work.

Comment: "You mail" might probably have understood that.

Comment: @StrangeDeveloper How to set gameobject behind coin meter. Coin meter is Ui Image.

Comment: Place your gameobject such that it gives a feel like it's behind that image. Open your game panel (window) keeping scene window opened and drag gameobject to place it behind the Image (observe the gameobject on game window). Tweak the position until you get a feel like it's really behind that image.

Comment: @StrangeDeveloper Thanks For you Help bro. I try again and again and it is done now. I just add a cube behind the camera while opening the Game Tab. I used the cube as Camera child so it will not any offset etc. Thanks for your support.